# How to get better performance this sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

How to get better performance this sql query using cross apply?

```
SELECT  DISTINCT TOP 10  acc.account_no
      FROM account (NOLOCK) acc
      CROSS APPLY(
       SELECT COUNT(1) AS piece
         FROM account (NOLOCK) acc2
        WHERE acc.account_no= acc2. account_no
          AND status= 'P'
      ) AS X

      CROSS APPLY(
       SELECT COUNT(1) AS piece2
         FROM account  (NOLOCK) acc2
        WHERE acc.account_no = acc2. account_no 
      ) AS Y
    WHERE X.piece= Y.piece2
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: This is a pure guess, but you might have success just adding `AND acc.status = 'P'` to the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Group By` and `Having`

```
SELECT account_no
FROM   Account
GROUP  BY account_no
HAVING Count(CASE
               WHEN status = 'P' THEN 1
             END) = Count(1)
```

Comment: I executed your query but It took longer. I would like to perform better with less rows instead. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @OKaradayi Did you try it with `SELECT TOP 10` ?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal Yes, i did.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need the account numbers where all the statuses are of value 'P'. Not sure about your TOP 10 without ORDER BY...

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 account_no
FROM  Account a (NOLOCK)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM account a1 (NOLOCK) WHERE a1.status <> 'P' AND a.Account_No = a1.Account_No)
```

Comment: This is worth trying. Note that if `status` is ever `NULL` you'll need to tweak the `WHERE` clause in the sub-query to handle that.

Comment: In my tests (with completely made up data), this came out top. +1